# Get a signal on each page fault

Tags: c, linux, x86-64

I want to set a signal handler in my application, so that the kernel sends a signal whenever it handles a page fault trap. Ofcourse I can use the `SIGSEGV` signal handler, but what I'm really interested in is to catch the page faults which occur on copy-on-write. For example after a fork (not followed by exec), the original process will get a page fault if it tries to write to some page. I want to get notified on such page faults. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suspect that you will have to hack the page fault handler.  Be very, very careful and always keep a bootable backup.

Comment: What happens if you take a page fault in the signal handler?

Comment: Exactly - double faults are bad in tennis, but worse in kernels.  A semaphore in non-paged pool might do but, for something like this, I would just inc a count in non-paged pool and have a driver return it when polled, (yes, Martin James just suggested polling for something:)

Comment: link from a deleted answer: http://lwn.net/Articles/550555/.  A user-space pagefault handing patch set from Andrea Arcangeli may have made this possible.  (But maybe only if you do a lot more work in userspace?).

Comment: `perf stat` / `perf record -e page-faults` can also count / record page-fault events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page faults are interrupts handled by do_page_fault()

```
http://www.stillhq.com/pdfdb/000446/data.pdf
```

Signals also generate an interrupt.  The difference is that the page fault interrupt is vectored to the code.  There is an explanation of what the code does.  IMO, always generating another interrupt in a an interrupt handler is a bad idea.

Tell us: What are you trying to accomplish?  Not how you think it should be done.

Comment: So, a Linux process doesn't has a way to know when a page fault occurred? I would like to print to stdout the address that caused each page fault. Is that possible?

Comment: No.  A page fault is something else; it is not a problem it is really an an expected feature of normal processing: an interrupt - the OS gets called to do something - while the process sits there blocked from doing anything - for a few microseconds maybe.