# Caching Linux vs direct on Hardware

Tags: c++, linux, caching, x86-64

I'm developing a small OS and tried to measure cpu caching on linux and with my small OS. Therefore I build a small example, which allocates a small chunk and reads it three times:

```
    size_t block_size( 1024 * 32 ); // 32 kB
    unsigned char *block = new unsigned char[block_size];

    for(unsigned int l = 0; l < 3; ++l) {
        unsigned int value(0);
        Cycles start(rdtsc());

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
            value += block[i];
        }

        Cycles end(rdtsc());

        printf("  %i: %u  -> %u\n", l, (duration(start, end)), value);
    }
```

I expected that the first run will be the slowest and the second and third will read from cache. But the results surprised me:

```
    Linux       Small OS
1.  79000       66000
2.  65644       65616
3.  65596       65600
```

The results after the first run are more or less the same, but the first is slower on linux. On my small os, the memory seems to be cached before running it the first time. Could that be because of the cpu prefetching? But if so, why is that not on linux prefetched? Any (other) ideas?

FYI: I measured both on the same intel x86_64 cpu, using just one thread on the first core. The cache size of L1 cache is 32kB. Increasing the block size makes no difference (tested up to 1024 kB).

Edit:
Here are some results using a greater block size:

```
# 64 kb
    Linux       Small OS
1.  158720      131368
2.  131124      131128
3.  65596       131132

# 512 kb
    Linux       Small OS
1.  1282644     1048960
2.  1048632     1048620
3.  1048636     1048620
```

A page fault should always generate the same absolute delay, shouldn't it? The results show, that the second run is always ~19 percent faster than the first on linux.

Comment: CPU cache is not necessarilly the only factor involved here. I wouldn't be surprised if the extra delay on the first iteration on linux is a page fault. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253139/get-a-signal-on-each-page-fault for how to test that theory.

Comment: Linux has virtual memory so may not actually allocate memory until it is used.

Comment: It's called on-demand paging - linux won't map a virtual page to a physical one until it's actually used. Don't confuse it with copying data to the disk, it's different.  There should be an option to disable this feature.

Comment: Thank you all for that information, didn't thought about a page fault. But why can't I see the cache in that example?

Comment: I added some more results.

Comment: @jagemue I'd suggest having a dedicated core for your process. So that no other process gets scheduled on the same physical core (keep in mind hyperthreading). Google for 'cpuset'. Also you need to check for that specific cpu how the cache is shared between cores.